# Catch file_get_contents timeout

Tags: php

Can you help me?

```
<?php 

$url='http://www.amigosdoforum.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/vingas.jpg';
$contents=file_get_contents($url);
if (false == $contents) {
  echo "Error!!";
} else {
  file_put_contents($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/system/images/aaa.jpg",$contents);
  echo "Success";
}

?>
```

This code is not catching "Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded".

I know that I'm able to change the limit, but I don't want it! I just want to catch this error and show to me if the code downloaded the image or not

What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping it in a try/catch block? http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Comment: Already tried but no success...

Comment: Ah, you can't catch it because it's a "fatal error". See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277224/how-do-i-catch-a-php-fatal-error

Comment: So, no ways to check if this URL image is valid to download?

Comment: Per the answers on that question, you could register a shutdown function to implement logic for when the image can't be downloaded.

Comment: What is your version of php? In a later version it is thrown as Error object implementing Throwable

Comment: @frz3993 PHP Version 5.4.31

Answer (score 0):

You cannot catch it because it's not an exception. You can register the shutdown function to handle this:

```
<?php
register_shutdown_function('shutdown');

function shutdown()
{
      // Your code to handle when PHP is down

}
```